# Button outline disappears randomly on Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode8

Really really simply question.

In my own computer when I create a button with Xcode, I can see the blue outline.

But, in my office's computer I do the same thing I can't see the blue outline (and can't figure out how much bigger the button is).

[image: Difference between computers, same Xcode version used]

What is happening?

I've recorded a video and uploaded to YouTube in order to be more clear — https://youtu.be/Bl_aOXxtIeA

PS: I've been trying to solve this thing on last 3 days, and no luck, even contacting a friend which is an iOS developer.

Comment: The outline isn't standard. By default, buttons don't have any kind of outline. The border you see there isn't an actual visible border, at least it wouldn't be if you ran the application and tried to view it on a device of some sort. The border there is some kind of visual assistance tool for showing more clearly what are the bounds of the button. Are you asserting that it is an actual border of the view, or do you recognize that it is just an addition of the IDE?

Comment: I know that is a visual assistance and must not be shown on the mobile app while running. I need this visual assistance while using Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: How to set outline as assistance in builder]

Folks, I just found the solution (trying by myself). Thanks for the replies too.